# Is there a way to have multiple "Open with" entries in Gnome context menu for files?

Tags: linux, gnome

I'm working with some files that I often open with 2 different applications. For example, I usually edit svg in Inkscape, so Inkscape is my default application for that file type. But also have to edit the source code of those files frequently, and I do that with a text editor.

Is it possible to have another entry in the context menu for a secondary application to open files?

e.g.
Open With Inkscape
Open With Code
Open With ...

[image]

System: Manjaro Linux (Gnome 44)